# Can the query below be corrected

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I need some help in  the query I have where I don't know if I am including the Correct GROUP BY Clause and selecting the fields from the right tables in the SELECT clause:

Below is the database Tables:

**Session Table**

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA
2          AAB
```

**Question Table**

```
SessionId  QuestionId  QuestionContent            QuestionMarks
1          1           What is 2+2?               2
1          2           What is 4+4?               3
2          1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?   5
2          2           What is 15+15?             5
2          3           What is 20+20 and 40+40?   7
```

**Answer Table**

```
AnswerId SessionId  QuestionId Answer
1        1          1          B
2        1          2          C
3        2          1          A
4        2          1          D
5        2          2          A
6        2          3          D
7        2          3          E
```

Below is the query:

```
   $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
   FROM Session s 
   INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
   JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
   WHERE SessionName = "AAB"
   GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
   ";
```

I want to display each question which belongs to session "AAB". So it should display QuestionId, QuestionContent, Answer and QuestionMarks like below:

```
 QuestionId  QuestionContent              Answer  QuestionMarks
    1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?     AD       5
    2           What is 15+15                A        5
    3           What is 20 + 20 and 40+40?   DE       7
```

At the moment if I am search for lets say questions in Session "AAB", it is displaying this below:

```
QuestionId  QuestionContent              Answer  QuestionMarks
    1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?     AD       5
    2           What is 15+15                A        5
    3           What is 20 + 20 and 40+40?   DE       7
    1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?     AD       5
    2           What is 15+15                A        5
    3           What is 20 + 20 and 40+40?   DE       7
    1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?     AD       5
    2           What is 15+15                A        5
    3           What is 20 + 20 and 40+40?   DE       7
    1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?     AD       5
    2           What is 15+15                A        5
    3           What is 20 + 20 and 40+40?   DE       7
    1           What is 10+10 and 11+11?     AD       5
    2           What is 15+15                A        5
    3           What is 20 + 20 and 40+40?   DE       7
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what your query is supposed to do. A table of the results you are expecting would help.

Comment: What is the output and desired result? It's easier to play in phpmyadmin than guessing :)

Comment: cant group by only be used against aggregate functions?

Comment: DEfinitely need a better understanding of a) what this data represents, b) what behavior you're expecting from your query, c) what behavior your getting.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was updating the question while you guys were posting comments on the output, I updated question to include the output wanted

Comment: is questionid a primary key? if so, the values should be unqiue, otherwise that will make joins very complicated

Comment: QuestionId and SessionId are primary keys in the question Table. They are composite keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer table has a session ID in it that it looks like you missed in your join. Also you shouldn't need the DISTINCT in your group_concat, unless your storage of the same answer for the same question/session multiple times is accidental, in which case I would solve that accident instead of coding a work around into the query.

```
SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
FROM Session s 
INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
             AND an.sessionID = s.sessionID
WHERE SessionName = "AAB"
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah I just figured it out also, exactly the same as the answer you had it. I was about to post my own answer but luckily saw your answer. Best answer anyway to you